# using CSS Responsive Image width and height with Google Structured Data recommendations

Tags: html, css, structured-data

Google says that it is better to put the width and height of an img in the html: "A web browser can begin to render a page even before images are downloaded"

[See Here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016)

```
<img src="some-address.jpg" width="20px" height="20px">
```

But, what if the img is in a responsive page?
I did not give any value and the img works well and adapts to any size. But, then the Google testing tool for structured data gives an error: "A value for the width field is required"
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

I tried to give that values:

```
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg"
width="100%" height="auto">
```

Here is the example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld49yLjs/2/)

It is responsive and it has the values. The error goes away. But I have read that Google requires numeric values.

How to put the width and height of an img in a responsive page?
I suppose that the use of structured data is always recommended. So, I must take into account what the Google testing tool says. Am I right?

Comment: _"**Specify a width and height for all images.** A web browser can begin to render a page even before images are downloaded, provided that it knows the dimensions to wrap non-replaceable elements around. Specifying these dimensions can speed up page loading and improve the user experience."_ - They said it's better to specify width and height. They never said in HTML. These values should exist in your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: @War10ck: If I specify only in the css the Google testing tool gives an error

Comment: What testing tool are you using? The one linked to is for structured data which is not the same as HTML markup validation. See [Introduction to Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) to read up more on what structured data is.

Comment: Can you update the title of this question to be more specific? Maybe something like "can I meet audit tools' desire for inline image dimensions while keeping my images responsive"?

Comment: @henry hows that?

Comment: @henry I though that structured data was always recommended?. If so, I don't understand why it must be specified. Perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: re: title: nice I think that'll make it easier for people wondering the same thing to find this question. re: structured data: I think you meant to tag @War10ck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Unor says here [link to a another question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/structured-data-img-width)

> Schema.org’s height/width properties are not for stating in which dimension the image should be displayed, but which dimension the image file has.

So I can put the responsive css as ususal in the css file:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

In the html, with structured data I have to give the width and height in px. The real pixels, as I can see in Photoshop:

```
 <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img src="some-address.jpg"/>
    <meta itemprop="url" content="some-address.jpg">
    <meta itemprop="width" content="20">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="20">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use css instead of attributes:

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg">
```

The article you refer to says:

> **Specify a width and height for all images.** A web browser can begin to render a page even before images are downloaded, provided that it knows the dimensions to wrap non-replaceable elements around. Specifying these dimensions can speed up page loading and improve the user experience. For more information about optimizing your images, see Optimizing Web Graphics on the site Let's Make the Web Faster.

So the reason of specifiing sizes in pixels is that browser will know the image size before it loads the image itself. And there is no sence in specifiing them in css for every image if it is unique and takes all place it needs. Now you are setting one value to `auto`. With `auto` browser have to get the image and only then it will be capable to calculate its dimensions ratio and use it. No any reasons to use attributes.

Comment: That's very nice way to make an image responsive. It just sets the height in ratio of the resized width to the original width and height

Comment: Is there any advantage to put in the css? There is the disadvantage that Google testing tool gives an error

Comment: Honestly the answer is you get used to seeing and ignoring it (in all the major testers, not just Google's). Wouldn't blame you for thinking that sounds crazy heh but there it is

Answer (score 0):

This is best done through a css style sheet as the width and height tags for images are generally considered bad practice.

```css
.imageclass{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px; /* whatever size is the biggest that you want */
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge.svg" class="imageclass" />
```

Comment: _"...width and height tags for images have been deprecated."_ - This is not quite accurate. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img). With HTML5 these attributes were reduced to only using pixels instead of pixels and percentages as in HTML4 but they are not deprecated by any means...

Comment: I tried to put the values in the css and the google testing tool gives an error

Comment: War10ck, you are right, I thought it had triggered some validation errors, but didn't fully check. It is generally considered bad practice however. I will edit.

Comment: In HTML5, it cannot be expressed in percentage, just pixels.

Comment: @ illinoistim if it cannot be percentage how you make it responsive?

Comment: It can be a percentage in the css, just not in the width attribute in the img tag. That makes it responsive.

Comment: @illinoistim if I put the width and heigh in the css google testing tool gives an error

Comment: @War10ck, I was thinking about tables, which I believe are depreciated.

Comment: @Nrc, I am not sure why the tool would do that. I know that I personally have had some issues with the Google tools before. Perhaps it is not picking us the css for some reason. You might want to do some research on the tool itself, or even ask another stackoverflow question about it to see if anyone else has the same issue.